# convert exponential to float in time.clock()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code

```
import time
t0=time.clock()
t1=time.clock()
time_difference = t1-t0
print time_difference
```

and output is

```
9.99999999998e-07
```

i want to assign value of t1-t0 to time_difference in float format having 2 digits after decimal how can i do that

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to print the value, you can use formatted output. This will print float values with two decimal digits after the dot: `print "%.2f" % time_difference`.

If you wish to update `time_difference` as a float value with two digits, you can use the `round` function (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round): `time_difference = round(time_difference, 2)`.

Comment: but i want to assign difference so that if i want i can compare the difference with float value

Comment: I expanded my answer for this case.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to convert an **exponential** to **float** is

```
e_variable = 4.3e-05 

convert_to_float = str('%.08f' % e_variable)

print convert_to_float
```